# Optional position arguments in python

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a script that can be executed both with a gui or without and it has some optional arguments such as -g for choosing to show gui, input path and output path, while this arguments are all optional i want them to be optional when gui is activated and non optional when executing the script without gui. How can i make this work?

Comment: Hi there. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you

Comment: If you use argparse, add `required=True` argument to `add_argument()` method.

Comment: @mece1390, `required` isn't allowed when the argument is `positional`.  Whether it is `required` is determined by the `nargs`.

Comment: Sounds like a good use for the `subparsers` feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest is the following: build an option processor function, based on `argparse` and processing `sys.argv` (the default). However, have that function receive a boolean argument, named, say, `batch_mode`, with a default value of `False`. Assign the value of `batch_mode` to all the places where you want conditional "required-ness" of arguments (depending on whether a GUI was invoked). Note that this function should both construct the parser and use it on `sys.argv`.

Now, run the function once with the default value of `batch_mode`. Then, if `-g` was **not** specified, run the function again, only this time pass `batch_mode=True`, making all the non-GUI arguments required.

Granted, this may entail two calls to the function, but the amount of extra coding required will be minimal.